# How to correctly (de)serialize nested objects in c#?

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

EDIT: sorry the code is working as intended. I just failed to test properly. Sorry for your inconvenience

I found some code here on SO to store and load objects (Code in the end). Storing the file is correctly working, but getting the file into object back again is not working when you have a list of objects:

Executing

```
Block b = loadFile<Block>("file");
Console.WriteLine(b.allCoins.Count); //is 0
```

results in an empty List. Checking the xml file they are all correctly stored, which means that the loading is somehow not working. **How can you correctly load the object?**

Here is the block class:

```
[Serializable]
    public class Block {
        public struct Coin {
            public string owner;
            public string name;

            public Coin(string n, string o) {
                owner = o;
                name = n;
            }
        };

        public int name;
        public List<string> hashOfParticles;
        public int numberOfTransactions;
        public List<Coin> allCoins;
     }
 }
```

Here is how i load the file into objects:

```
public static T loadFile<T>(string fileName) {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) { return default(T); }

            T objectOut = default(T);

            try {
                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDocument.Load(fileName);
                string xmlString = xmlDocument.OuterXml;

                using (StringReader read = new StringReader(xmlString)) {
                    Type outType = typeof(T);

                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(outType);
                    using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(read)) {
                        objectOut = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                        reader.Close();
                    }

                    read.Close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //Log exception here
            }

            return objectOut;
        }
```

Here is the code which stores the file:

```
public static void storeFile<T>(T serializableObject, string fileName) {
            if (serializableObject == null) { return; }

            try {
                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializableObject.GetType());
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) {
                    serializer.Serialize(stream, serializableObject);
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    xmlDocument.Load(stream);
                    xmlDocument.Save(fileName);
                    stream.Close();
                    Form1.instance.addToLog("Storing \"" + fileName +  "\" succesful");
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Form1.instance.addToLog("Storing \"" + fileName + "\" NOT succesful");

            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the xml input you are using?

Comment: is `load<Block>("file");` at the beginning meant to be `loadFile<Block>("file");` - ie the method you have put in at the end?

Comment: Please show the code that serializes as well.

Comment: @SilasReinagel: https://puu.sh/x9TCB/13d6106e75.png
I removed some filler stuff, but the overall structure is this

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i added the code to the post

Comment: My first thought is to try converting your Fields to public properties. Most serializers require that.

Comment: You are transferring the data back and forth a lot, why not simply serialize directly to a file stream for the filename? Also you say "loading is somehow not working", well how do you know? What does the objects look like?

Comment: I was successfully able to save and load a simple object using your methods. Please explain how you came to the conclusion that it doesn't work.

Comment: I know that loading is not working because i check the object before i serialize it (it is not empty!), i check the xml (data is there!), but after loading the list (list<coin>) inside the object is empty.

Iam not sure what you mean with transfering the data back and forth. Right now efficiency is not of concern, because i want to get started with C#. Once everything is working ill try to improve my code

Comment: ok, so this is a little bit awkward. More testing resulted in correctly getting the list. Somehow my code resulted in overriding the list.

Comment: By "back and forth", here's an alternative version of your methods that access the files directly without going through an XmlDocument, https://gist.github.com/lassevk/77934f95568fe409d67c35181ec7cec8

Comment: Look at my response from Saturday : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645828/recursively-add-elements-to-root-element-for-creating-xml-in-c-sharp/45649533#45649533